# Need a regular expression so that ^[a-zA-Z0-9][.a-zA-Z0-9_-]*$ works for all language

Tags: regex

I need a regular expression which should match in all languages, like Japanese, Korean, Spanish, French, Italian, etc.

The expression is I'm trying to replicate is:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9][.a-zA-Z0-9_-]*$
```

Comment: BTW, which language you talk/using?

Comment: You seem to have found the solution already. What's the problem?

Comment: Define what you mean by "work"

Comment: The solution is very different depending on which dialect of regexp you are using. In Ruby, which uses Oniguruma engine, `"私は57.5-58です".match(/[[:alpha:][:digit:]][[:alpha:][:digit:]._-]*/)` works. In JavaScript, it does not.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using PCRE (Perl/PHP/Python), do this instead:

```
^[\p{L}\p{N}][\p{L}\p{N}._-]*$
```

Or:

```
^[\p{L}\p{Nd}][\p{L}\p{Nd}._-]*$
```

This will match any letter or number in any UTF-8 string.

Now, `.`, `_`, and `-` get a bit trickier! You could match any punctuation by `\p{P}`, but this will include more than the three characters listed. These Unicode escape sequences are explained [here](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php) and [here](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlunicode.html#Unicode-Character-Properties).

As [@Amadan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/240443/amadan) mentioned, this will work in Ruby or with the [Oniguruma library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oniguruma), and it will also work in POSIX regular expression engines:

```
/[[:alpha:][:digit:]][[:alpha:][:digit:]._-]*/
```

A POSIX regular expression uses [bracket expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html) instead of of `\` escape sequences.